# Corrective Room EQ & RTA apps

Tags: monitor-calibration, rta

I thought someone had asked a similar question on here, but I can't find it at the moment, maybe it was another site. Forgive me if I'm repeating.

I'm looking for recommendations of rack-mounted Graphic EQs to have in-line for our monitor chain to do some minor room correction. Currently we have 3 Rane ME60 units feeding our LCRLsRs and an Rane AC22 Active Crossover. They're old, noisy and dusty and, while a good cleaning might satisfy, I've been tapped to look into replacement options.

The main problem is matching our center channel (which is mounted behind an "acoustically transparent" screen) to our L&R which are not.

Happy to hear any advice you guys would hand out.

Additionally, I'm certain some of you have iPhones and are using one of the various RTA apps. Any qualms, praises, pointers, or endorsements? We're hoping to not have to buy a real one... we'll see about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Steve,

The DBX DriveRack 260 is a popular one on dub stages. There's a thread on the DUC about this here: http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=253954&highlight=room+eq

I have one of the RTA's for my Ipod and I find the Low end response just isn't very accurate, at least with the stock mics - makes sense since they're really designed for voice. If you attached a really good mic via one of the input options then that might change, but then you'd probably negate any real cost savings. I do however like the SPL meter for quick checks.

Comment: Thanks @Sonsey. I never think to look on the duc for anything outside of ProTools. That's exactly the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have RTA Lite installed on my iPod Touch. I've never configured it or done any proper testing so I've no idea how acurate it actually is.

+1 on a quick SPL checker though.